# MySQL Select duplicities according date interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table *orders*:

| id | login_name | success | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | login1 | 0 | 2021-01-05 |
| 2 | login2 | 0 | 2021-01-06 |
| 3 | login3 | 0 | 2021-01-08 |
| 4 | login1 | 1 | 2021-01-04 |
| 5 | login2 | 0 | 2021-01-01 |

I need to select id, login_name with success=0 for which exist another order with order_date older or younger than 60 days.

The result should be:
1 - login1, 2 - login2, 5 - login2

I have this, but I think that is not a right way:

```
SELECT id, login_name, COUNT(*)
FROM orders
WHERE success=0 
GROUP BY login_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "older or younger than 60 days"?

Comment: I mean this `abs(datediff(rr.order_date, r.order_date)) <= 60`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXISTS as follows:

```
SELECT id, login_name, COUNT(*)
  FROM orders r
 WHERE success=0 
   and exists 
      (select 1 from orders rr
        where rr.login = r.login
          and abs(datediff(rr.order_date, r.order_date)) <= 60
          and rr.id <> r.id 
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want orders that appear within 60 days of each other, you can use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             lag(order_date) over (partition by login_name order by order_date) as prev_order_date,
             lead(order_date) over (partition by login_name order by order_date) as lead_order_date
      from orders o
     ) o
where prev_order_date > dateadd(day, -60, order_date) or
      next_order_date < dateadd(day, 60, order_date);
```